# Debug update-command-not-found on Debian

Tags: debian, command-not-found

What is the problem I am having with command-not-found?  Is it a known bug?

```
$ dpkg-query --show command-not-found
command-not-found   0.2.38-4

$ installme
Could not find the list of available applications, run update-command-not-found as root to fix this
installme: command not found

$ sudo update-command-not-found
```

This command returns after less than a second, and does not actually help:

```
$ installme
Could not find the list of available applications, run update-command-not-found as root to fix this
installme: command not found
```

---

```
$ sudo strace -f update-command-not-found
...
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/fnmatch.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 5
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3602, ...}) = 0
read(5, "\3\363\r\n\250\321\200Xc\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0sa\0\0\0d\0"..., 4096) = 3602
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3602, ...}) = 0
read(5, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(5)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/var/lib/apt/lists", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getdents(3, /* 21 entries */, 32768)    = 1584
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
umask(022)                              = 022
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fc5a847c0c0}, {sa_handler=0x5633718d3e60, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fc5a847c0c0}, 8) = 0
brk(0x563372c40000)                     = 0x563372c40000
munmap(0x7fc5a7180000, 262144)          = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Debian bug #857090](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=857090).

> This seems to be the case when you run update-command-not-found
>   without any Contents-file downloaded. If you run "apt update" after
>   installation it works without problems.
>
> I think update-command-not-found should make it clearer that you need
>   to update the apt-cache prior to running it.